# ID not detectable

Tags: sas

I am using SAS 9.4, and I have a question.

All my syntax works without any errors. I wanted to check one case (tenantid=8041020430506) to see if variables are created as I intended.

```
proc print data=green1;
    where tenantid=8041020430506;
    var tenantid var1-var3;
run;
```

Well, NOTE: No observations were selected from data set WORK.GREEN1.

```
proc print data=green1;
    where 8041020430505<tenantid<8041020430507;
    var tenantid var1-var3;
run;
```

This one prints all for `tenantid=8041020430506` without any error message.

`tenantid` is a numeric variable with `length=8. / format=17. / informat=17`.

I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You have a numerical precision issue. It's likely 8041020430506.000001.

ID's should be stored as a character variable to avoid this issue.